# How to use tkinter to turn on and off a led with a raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have this code that is in my raspberry pi, that will produce 2 buttons, and only 1 of them will ever work, the bottom one doesn't work, even though it is the exact same except the opposite function. code is below.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
def on():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
def off():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
tob = Button(root, text = "Press to activate", command = on)
tob.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
tofb = Button(root, text = "Press to deactivate", command = offer)
tofb.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

the circuitry works, because it turns on the led, its the code that doesn't work

Comment: `offer` != `off`.

Comment: FYI. You should only be using the `GPIO.setmode` function once in your program. It serves no additional purpose resetting the mode each time you press a button. Consider placing it before `GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)`

Answer (score 1):

maybe change the callback ?

command = offer

to

command = off

Comment: it doesn't matter what the name is

Comment: @Travis: it does when the function is one name but you call it with another name.